# Will setting your time to April 1st bring back April Fools features on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As most people know Minecraft had an April Fools update that removed the inventory entirely only allowing you to pick up one block/item at a time.


I was not able to play on April first though so I missed it, but still want to try it out because it seems like a pretty fun twist on Minecraft to try to do stuff with it according to videos I have watched. I wondered if setting my computer time to April 1st would bring back the April Fools update. I'm not talking about going back to previous versions, since I can already do that, I just want this single update to test out.


Would it bring it back, or am I unable to go back to it? Are you able to go back for older one-day updates too made before this one?

Comment: I don't think that the date trick will work. You just need to find the snapshot somewhere, which is called "22w13oneBlockAtATime"

Comment: Were those features available by default on April 1st, or would you still have needed to use the snapshot?

Comment: @Pikatchoo32 you needed to download a specific snapshot to play that version

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unlike e.g. gift box textures on chests during Christmas and pumpkins on mobs during Halloween, April fools snapshots are actually separate game versions. Which snapshot is considered the latest by the launcher is specified in [a file on Mojang's servers](https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json), so your system time does not affect it.

You can still access Minecraft 22w13oneblockatatime (or any other April Fools version) following the same process as you would to play any other old version of minecraft: by clicking "New installation" in the launcher and selecting the appropriate version in the drop-down menu.

Comment: For those new to selecting snapshot versions: You need to have "Enable Snapsots" checked in order to be able to select them.

Answer (score -2):

1. Download Minecraft Launcher from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net)
2. Go to Java Edition and click the installations tab.
3. Click add installation.
4. Choose the snapshot that has oneblockatatime at the end of it.
5. Select the installation and play!

Comment: What information does this convey that is not already conveyed by my answer?

Comment: @pppery It conveys it in a more readable form.